# Trying to compare two tables and add same EPC value to another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to compare two columns in two different tables in a same data base (PriorityLevel table EPC column and table3 EPC column). Different values of EPC in these two tables is going to table2. But the following error occurrs.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (EPC)
  SELECT EPC
  FROM priorityLevel
  WHERE priorityLevel.EPC != table3.EPC;
```

Error

> The multi-part identifier "table3.EPC" could not be bound.

Comment: There is no `table3` in your query? You probably need to join it on somehow.

Comment: INSERT INTO table2 (EPC )
SELECT EPC
FROM priorityLevel 
INNER JOIN table3 on
priorityLevel.EPC != table3.EPC ;

Comment: Please update the question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (EPC)
SELECT PL.EPC
FROM   priorityLevel PL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT  1
                     FROM    table3 T3
                     WHERE   PL.EPC = T3.EPC
                  );
```

Comment: Make sure that you actually have a dbo.table3 in your database.

Comment: Data Source=ASUS;Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False                                                ***why this Encrypt and TrustServerCertificate become False

Comment: Your answer code was worked once . But now it is not working.The thread 0x1c4c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x196c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x2c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[5892] UHFDemo.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0). shows in output window.

Comment: Not sure from where you are running this from. But if you are not running this in database directly, then 1> Go open your SSMS, 2> Select the proper database where all these 3 tables are: dbo.table2, dbo.priorityLevel, dbo.table3 , 3> Execute the query . Once you confirm that it is working in database end, then go check where in application layer /front end you have issue in code/connection which is showing you that error.